# How to implement multiple "On Error GoTo" statements?

Tags: excel, vba

If there is an error opening the file, I want the to skip the error and move on to the next part.

This is to be done in "5 parts". If the file opens (i.e., no error) then the line `GoTo PartEnd` tells the program to skip to the end and finish.

Can I not use `On Error GoTo` inside of another `On Error GoTo` code?

```vb
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim wbName As String
    
    On Error GoTo Part2 'If the file doesn't open go to Part2
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("N:\Public\Finance Public\" & Year & " MUV\" & "MUV" & MonthShort & Day5 & YearShort & "_" & Day7)
    GoTo PartEnd 'If the file opens skip Part2 through Part5 and go to PartEnd
    
Part2:
    On Error GoTo Part3
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("N:\Public\Finance Public\" & Year & " MUV\" & "MUV" & MonthShort & Day4 & YearShort)
    GoTo PartEnd
    
Part3:
    On Error GoTo Part4
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("N:\Public\Finance Public\" & Year & " MUV\" & "MUV" & MonthShort & Day3 & YearShort)
    GoTo PartEnd

Part4:
    On Error GoTo Part5
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("N:\Public\Finance Public\" & Year & " MUV\" & "MUV" & MonthShort & Day2 & YearShort)
    GoTo PartEnd

Part5:
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler1
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("N:\Public\Finance Public\" & Year & " MUV\" & "MUV" & MonthShort & Day1 & YearShort)

PartEnd:
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement clearly says that if an error handler is already active then  the new error handler won't handle the error.  So your On Error Goto Part2 was triggered and without a Resume the On Error Goto Part3 won't work.

Comment: Please don't paste images of code - you can copy/paste as text and format using the `{}` button.   In the VB editor go to Tools >> Options >> General tab and make sure "Error Trapping" is not set to "Break on all errors"

Comment: From the SO FAQ: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also see [mre] and [ask]. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Ok I get I need to add a "Resume" in my code. But where do i put that..

Comment: @KenWhite Ok i have added in code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wow this was quite difficult but finally figured it out on my own. Ended up playing around and figuring it out. Code below. Thanks for the help anyways.

```
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim wbName As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("N:\Public\Finance Public\" & Year & " MUV\" & "MUV" & MonthShort & Day5 & YearShort & "_" & Day7)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Else
    GoTo NextPart
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("N:\Public\Finance Public\" & Year & " MUV\" & "MUV" & MonthShort & Day4 & YearShort)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Else
    GoTo NextPart
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("N:\Public\Finance Public\" & Year & " MUV\" & "MUV" & MonthShort & Day3 & YearShort)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Else
    GoTo NextPart
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("N:\Public\Finance Public\" & Year & " MUV\" & "MUV" & MonthShort & Day2 & YearShort)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Else
    GoTo NextPart
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler1
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("N:\Public\Finance Public\" & Year & " MUV\" & "MUV" & MonthShort & Day1 & YearShort)
   
NextPart:
```